# Passport validity requirements for a EU resident (but not a EU citizen) to travel within Schengen

Tags: schengen, passports, residency, ukrainian-citizens

It is known that in order to *enter* the Schengen area a non-EU citizen should have a passport  which

1. [expires at least three months after than the supposed date of leaving the Schengen area](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k6678075-New_Schengen_rule_regarding_passport_validity-Air_Travel.html)
2. [is not older than 10 years](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/passport-requirements.html)
3. [the renewed passports older than 10 years are not allowed](http://www.embassyportugal-us.org/Embassy_of_Portugal/Visa_Info_for_Schengen_States.html)

However I was not able to find any information on what happens if a third-country national is a EU long-term resident in a Schengen member country, has a passport issued some 9,5 years ago and he/she extends the validity of passport in the consulate of his/her country of citizenship for, say, another 10 years while staying in the Schengen area.

> *The question is:* will this extended passport be valid for traveling **within the Schengen area** (at least until 10 years from the date of issue of the passport, i.e. for a few months remaining until the passport becomes exactly 10 years old)?

I am not sure to which extent the answer to this question depends on a specific Schengen country to which one wants to travel. If this is the case, I am particularly interested in the possibility of traveling to Austria, Germany, Poland and Italy.

Comment: What country is the passport, and when you DO plan to leave, how old will the passport be then?

Comment: The country that issued the passport is Ukraine, the intended travel will take place when the passport is roughly 9 years 10 months old. Let me stress however that all travel is supposed to be *within* the Schengen area, i.e., the person in question is already there. 

Basically the point I would like to find out is whether extending the passport would make it valid for travel within the Schengen area for at least these few months until it is 10 years old.

Answer (score 6):

Even if there are general rules on which documents are accepted when *entering* or *leaving* the Schengen area, it is up to each member state to decide which documents are recognized and required for a foreigner to stay in the country. This has the odd implication that you as a citizen of a Schengen state don't need a passport to cross the border to another member state, but may be required by national law in the other state to be in posession of a passport to stay there.

For Germany, you can find the list of [officially recognized foreign travel documents here](http://www.migrationsrecht.net/allgemeinverfuegung-fuer-die-anerkennung-auslaendischer-paesse-vom-18.02.2005/dokument-ansehen.html) (in German). There is no absolute requirement that passports may not be valid for more than 10 years, there are however for several countries restrictions that only passports issued after a said date are valid. One odd example would be Turkmen passports, which are valid when issued after 1996, even if they have no expiration date at all.

As you can see from the German regulations (16 pages of fine print), it is not possible to give you a general answer. As Mark Mayo suggested, if you ask if a specific document is valid, you may get better help.

---

Ukrainian regular passports are in Germany valid without any restrictions. The symbols and abbreviations used in the German list are not quite intuitive to understand, but "JA 3) (2000)" means that the 2000 series of the passport is recognized, but hat earlier issued passport are also still recognized as long as they are not expired. Remark 3) is not applicable to regular passports.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info regarding Germany. As I wrote in response to Mark Mayo's comment above, the passport is issued by Ukraine, so if you (or perhaps somebody else reading this) could please extract from your link the info regarding the Ukrainian passports, and my question specifically, I'd greatly appreciate that -- I have found the Ukraine's entry in the table on your link but I am somewhat confused as to how it relates to my question. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added info abou the Ukrainian passport in my answer.

Comment: Special thanks for editing in the Ukrainian passports info!